# Angular 7 server side rendering deployment in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: angular, angular7

I created Angular 7 project with server side rendering using universal tool.

It works fine on local machine no problem and the dist folder including server and browser folder and server.js

The question is how to use that in ubuntu server using apache and the app will be in sub folder and how can I keep the app runing if i closed the terminal?

I searched a lot and used pm2 approach the process run but I didn't find how to access site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i was using apache port when i changed the port and open new port through firewall works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to configure your web server as a Reverse Proxy to point at the Node server.

For Nginx the configuration may look like this:

```
location / { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Make sure your have set for `proxy_pass` the same port as defined in your node server file.

Next you should copy the dist directory to your web server. Then you can start the node server in the background with **pm2** as you already correctly mentioned:

```
npm install pm2 -g
pm2 start /var/www/html/server.js // this is the entry point of your universal server
```

This will start up the Node server. You can check if Node is responding properly by running `curl localhost:8080`. If this returns the source code of your application, you are good to go.

Finally after you restart you web server, your Angular application should be accessable from outside by calling your servers IP or hostname.

---

**Edit** - To fully enable proxies on your apache server, run the following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

Comment: What about apache ?

Comment: i opened the port but the port opens the default apache page not the defined folder this is host file 
how to point the port to to angular app ?

Comment: @Roufail Did you enable the proxy module on your apache server? If not check my edit. Also it would be helpful if you could adjust your question and add the configs of your virtual host, so we may check them.

Comment: I am sorry for delay the problem is i was using apache port when i change it and open new port through firewall works fine.